# iOS - how to merge "on my iPad" Notes to iCloud after iCloud already activated?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, icloud, notes.app

I keep encountering this problem at friends' and it's always the same thing. They wonder why Notes does not sync up to iCloud.

I grab their iPad or iPhone and realize that their notes are written to "On My iPad" or "On My iPhone".

I then google around for a decent app, never find one (is there really no such thing?)..

And wind up copy-pasting them from "On My iPad" to "iCloud" one at a time. Thankfully this time he only had 27 notes so it didn't take that long.

Sometimes I panic and start emailing the Notes one at a time to his email address and then paste them onto his iCloud via OS X action.

Is there really no better way? I've checked around for advice and it seems to always be "Just email them" "Just copypaste them".

Any ideas?

Comment: @DaniSpringer.com Nope. However, I found a method eventually, which was to get to iOS9 and enter Edit-mode and just simply move the "on my iPad" -notes to the iCloud. Instead of pasting them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you can do, on at least iOS 9.

1. Launch Notes on your iPhone or iPad.
2. While on the list of notes, tap *Edit* to enter edit mode.
3. Tap *Move All* to move all notes or, alternatively, select the note(s) you want to move and tap *Move To...*
4. Select *iCloud Notes*

That's all.

Answer (score -1):

If you already took notes locally on your iPad or iPhone prior to enabling iCloud note sync, there is not much you can do to push these notes to iCloud once you enable iCloud note sync.

I believe that there are some paid apps for Windows that can do the trick all at once but not sure if it would not just be better to copy the notes one by one.